# Using a "superclass" object to handle inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am making a program that solves a number of similar problems.

I am starting with a class that looks like (for example):

```
class problem {
  void init();
  void solve();
  int print_result();
}
```

but then I would like to extend this class to different problems:

```
class problem_A : problem {
  void init();
  void solve();
  void print_result();
}

class problem_B : problem {
  void init();
  void solve();
  void print_result();
}

...
```

But in the main interface I would like to have a single object for either of the problems (A, B, ...) and handle them like:

```
obj.init();
obj.solve();
obj.print_result();
```

How do I achieve this? What type should obj be?

Comment: Have a look into the [Template Method Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method). Also note, that without having virtual functions or use static polymorphism, you cannot override a base classes behavior.

Comment: sounds like factory pattern.

Comment: @GaneshKamath That's just a more decoupled variant.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to call `init()` then `solve()` then `print_result()`, it's best to wrap this up in the (for C++) awkwardly named Template Method Pattern:

```
class problem {
public:
    virtual ~problem() = default;

    void run() {
        init();
        solve();
        print_result();
    }

protected:
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void solve() = 0;
    virtual void print_result() = 0;
};
```

And then each of your explicit problems just have to provide implementations for those functions:

```
class problem_A : public problem {
protected:
    void init() override { .. }
    void solve() override { .. }
    void print_result() override { .. }
};

problem* p = new problem_A(..);
p->run(); // inits, solves, and prints the results for problem A
```

Answer (score 1):

You stick with your original class, but make the methods pure `virtual`

```
class problem {
  virtual void init() = 0;
  virtual void solve() = 0;
  virtual int print_result() = 0;
}
```

Then you can `override` these functions in the derived classes

```
class problem_A : problem {
  virtual void init() override;
  virtual void solve() override;
  virtual void print_result() override;
}
```

Then you can make your object as follows:

```
problem* obj = new problem_A;
obj->init();
obj->solve();
obj->print_result();
```

This will invoke `problem_A`'s methods, but you can use a pointer to the base class `problem`. Obviously make sure you clean up the memory

```
delete obj;
```

Or use smart pointers

```
std::unique_ptr<problem> = std::unique_ptr<problem>(new problem_A);
```

Comment: Not really, either make the base class functions pure virtual, or use the Template Method pattern.

Comment: You also need inherit using `public` and make the methods `public`

Comment: @Sean Or make everything a `struct`. Cyber, you need a virtual destructor in the base class.